# Copying With Progress Bar not working

Tags: c#, copy, progress-bar

I kinda have a problem. I'm trying to make a form that copies stuff from point A to B with a statusbar. Now the copying works fine but the statusbar just isn't doing anything..
Anyone got any clue?

```
public partial class Form4A : Form
{
    public Form4A()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        OtherSettings();
        BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); // Starts wow copying
    }

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string SourcePath = RegistryRead.ReadOriginalPath();
        string DestinationPath = RegistryRead.ReadNewPath();

        if (!Directory.Exists(SourcePath))
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                //Now Create all of the directories
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));

                //Copy all the files
                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*",
                    SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));


                BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i);
            }
        }
    }
    private void backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Change the value of the ProgressBar to the BackgroundWorker progress.
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        // Set the text.
        this.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the destination path isn't already there before you call this function? Also it looks like you're not presenting progress updates correctly, instead you're copying all files 100 times.

Comment: It should `if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath))` without the "!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say: `if (!Directory.Exists(DestinationPath))`. This means that the loop will never be executed, if the desination path exists. Make sure you delete the DestinationPath before you test your code!

EDIT:

```
if (Directory.Exists(SourcePath)) {
    //Now Create all of the directories 
    string[] allDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(SourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    int numberOfItems = allDirectories.Length + allFiles.Length;
    int progress = 0;

    foreach (string dirPath in allDirectories) {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
        progress++;
        BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100 * progress / numberOfItems);
    }

    //Copy all the files 
    foreach (string newPath in allFiles) {
        File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(SourcePath, DestinationPath));
        progress++;
        BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress(100 * progress / numberOfItems);
    }
}
```

Comment: tss, thank you for pointing that out, it's supposed to be the sourcepath... thing is I just got this code from the internet because i can't figure out how it works

Comment: So you just copied the code and didn't actually assign the ProgressChanged event?  Select the BGW in the designer, click the lightning bolt icon in the Properties window and double-click ProgressChanged.

Comment: And also check if the DoWork event handler is assigned as well.

Comment: I did assign it though, but still got the same problem

Comment: I suggest you to place a breakpoint at the beginning of the BackgroundWorker_DoWork method. And then step through it line by line. You will also see, if the method gets called at all. Remember: The debugger is your best friend!

Comment: It does, because it does copy, but it doesn't update the status :<

Comment: If I understand your code right, then it would copy the same directories and files one hundert times! See my edit for another solution.

Comment: Thank you jesus ^^ I have no idea how you did it but it works ^^  Thanks so much for your help, might seem retarded but i've been screwing around trying to get this to work for like 5 hours or something so ^^